# ca-certificates is broken or not fully installed

Tags: wget, github

Running
sudo wget -O ruby-install-0.7.0.tar.gz https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/archive/v0.7.0.tar.gz

I get the message

ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:

Running
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates

I get the message
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ca-certificates is broken or not fully installed

There appears to be a problem in /usr/local/bin/c_rehash that may relate to the problem. Lines 15-16 are:

my $dir = ;
my $prefix = ;

For my Ubuntu install, I believe the correct info here is to run:
openssl version -a

OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"

but that certs directory is empty. However /etc/ssl/certs has the certs. Do I just need to symbolic link the directory with the certs, and what may have changed to break wget today after working for years?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

edit line 15-16 of /usr/local/bin/c_rehash to read:

my $dir = "/usr/local/ssl";

my $prefix = "/usr/local/ssl";

cd /usr/local/ssl/certs

sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/* ./

and now wget works as before upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04